# How to join multiple tables with one table?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2014

I'm working on an SQL project, but I found a problem while retrieving data from the database. There are four tables as you can see in the following screenshot:

[image: DB diagram]

So my query is about calculating the sum of the units from the tables `transac_EUR_M10_17` and `transac_EUR_M09_17`.

I tried the following SQL Server query but the results are false:

```
SELECT cntry.cod_country
    , rg.nom_region
    , SUM(tr.unite) as [sum units M09]
    , SUM(tr1.unite) as [sum units M10]   
FROM [Backup].[dbo].[transac_EUR_M09_17] as tr    
INNER JOIN [Backup].[dbo].[COUNTRY] as cntry ON tr.[cod_country] = cntry.[cod_country]  
INNER JOIN [Backup].[dbo].Region as rg   ON rg.[cod_country] = cntry.[cod_country]  
INNER JOIN [Backup].[dbo].[transac_EUR_M10_17] AS tr1  ON tr1.[cod_country] = cntry.[cod_country]
where tr.cod_region = rg.cod_region 
    AND tr1.cod_region = rg.cod_region 
Group BY cntry.cod_country
    , rg.nom_region   
ORDER BY SUM(tr.unite)
    , SUM(tr1.unite) DESC
```

Do you have any advice about how to join two tables with one permanent table?

Comment: What does "the results are false" mean? I assume that means the values are not what you want. But we have no idea what you are getting or what you expect to get. Here is a great place to start. https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve And also https://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Comment: We're really going to need some DDL and Sample data to go with this one. There's plenty of guides on how to provide it, such as on [SSC](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Best+Practices/61537/). When you say that your results are "false" why are they not what you expected? *I'm hazarding a guess that, perhaps, there **are** One/Many to Many relationships in there, and it's causing the data to grow exponentially.*

Comment: Can you explain, `how to join 2 tables with one permenant table` What is it you are trying to do. sample data and schemas are a must if you want more help.

Comment: Can I just use this post to voice my frustration with the StackOverflow editing system and how often I spend like 3-5 minutes editing a post and then have the site balk because there's another edit in queue? Really frustrating, and a waste of time.

Comment: How can we help if you don't give information.  We can't read your mind.  What are you trying to do???  Where's the sample input???  Where's the expected output???  Here's a good information of how to ask question.  https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

looking at your data diagram, I would structure my code a bit differently to make sure I get the desired results.

First join the 2 primary tables by Country and region
Then filter by using the country and region tables, omitting any where clause because you include all conditions in the join clauses.

like so

```
SELECT cntry.cod_country
    , rg.nom_region
    , SUM(tr.unite) as [sum units M09]
    , SUM(tr1.unite) as [sum units M10]   
FROM [Backup].[dbo].[transac_EUR_M09_17] as tr    
INNER JOIN [Backup].[dbo].[transac_EUR_M10_17] AS tr1  ON tr1.[cod_country] = tr.[cod_country]
                                                       AND tr1.[cod_region] = tr.[cod_region]
INNER JOIN [Backup].[dbo].[COUNTRY] as cntry ON tr.[cod_country] = cntry.[cod_country]  
INNER JOIN [Backup].[dbo].Region as rg   ON rg.[cod_country] = cntry.[cod_country]  
                                        AND rg.[cod_region] = tr.[cod_region]
Group BY cntry.cod_country, rg.nom_region   
ORDER BY SUM(tr.unite), SUM(tr1.unite) DESC
```

This still may not produce your desired results, but from what you have given, it should correctly join your tables.

Answer (score 0):

Unless cod_country is a unique column, those joins are bound to cause duplicate columns.

If you have 2 rows with the same country in 09_17 and the same thing in 10_17 it is going to duplicate both rows in the first table to duplicate, hence messing up your sums.

EDIT: And the same applies to any other table you're joining with